# Bernoulli Polynomial BesselJ expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

I have been reading a paper on classes of polynomials and it gives the following series:
$$J_{\nu }(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(x^{\nu } B_n\left(x^2\right)\right) \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+2} 2^{-\nu -2 n+2}}{\Gamma (n+\nu )}+(-1)^{n+1} 2^{1-n} J_{n+\nu -1}(1)\right)}{n!}$$ 
$$J_{\nu }(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((-1)^n 2^{-\nu -2 n-1} \left(\, _0F_1\left(;n+\nu +1;-\frac{1}{4}\right)+1\right)\right) \left(x^{\nu } E_n\left(x^2\right)\right)}{n! \Gamma (n+\nu +1)}$$ 
where $B_n$ is Bernoulli Polynomial and $E_n$ is the Euler Polynomial
but I try Taylor series but it is different it is seem convergent and fast for the most values it possible get it from Euler Naclaurin series

Comment: Where did you see these? Also, I couldn't find these in Watson's book on Bessel functions.

Comment: you can find it  in https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022247X66901466/1-s2.0-0022247X66901466-main.pdf?_tid=844f3d91-591c-458e-b699-df6e1167df67&acdnat=1546165024_8d706ad4b64a9609b6325b2fc05abf6e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first expression follows from theorem 1 in the paper linked in the comment. It states that, under suitable growth properties,
\begin{equation}
 f(X)=\int_0^1f(t)\,dt+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[ f^{(n-1)}(1)-f^{(n-1)}(0)\right]\frac{B_n(X)}{n!}  \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation} 
Starting from the series expansion for the Bessel function
\begin{equation}
 J_\nu(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m2^{-2m-\nu}}{\Gamma(m+1+\nu)}\frac{x^{2m+\nu}}{m!}
\end{equation} 
denoting $X=x^2$ and
\begin{equation}
 f(X)=x^{-\nu} J_\nu(x)
\end{equation} 
we have directly
\begin{equation}
 f(X)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m2^{-2m-\nu}}{\Gamma(m+1+\nu)}\frac{X^m}{m!}
\end{equation} 
so that
\begin{equation}
 f^{(n-1)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{-2n-\nu+2}}{\Gamma(n+\nu)}
\end{equation} 
Now, since
\begin{equation}
 \frac{d}{dX}=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}
\end{equation} 
we have
\begin{equation}
 \left[\frac{d}{dX} \right]^{n-1}\left( f(X) \right)=2^{-n+1}\left[\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx} \right]^{n-1}\left( \frac{J_\nu(x)}{ x^{\nu}} \right)
\end{equation} 
Using the [derivation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Recurrence_relations) for the Bessel function, we deduce
\begin{equation}
 f^{(n-1)}(X)=(-1)^{n-1}2^{-n+1}\frac{J_{n+\nu-1}(X)}{X^{n+\nu-1}}
\end{equation} 
and thus
\begin{equation}
 f^{(n-1)}(1)=(-1)^{n-1}2^{-n+1}J_{n+\nu-1}(1)
\end{equation} 
We have also from G\&R (6.561.9)
\begin{align}
 \int_0^1f(t)\,dt&=2\int_0^1 x^{-\nu+1}J_\nu(x)\,dx\\
 &=\frac{2^{2-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}-2J_{\nu-1}(1)
\end{align} 
Plugging all these results into expression \eqref{eq1}, one obtains
\begin{equation}
 x^{-\nu} J_\nu(x)=\frac{2^{2-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}-2J_{\nu-1}(1)
+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[ (-1)^{n-1}2^{-n+1}J_{n+\nu-1}(1)-\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{-2n-\nu+2}}{\Gamma(n+\nu)}\right]\frac{B_n(x^2)}{n!} 
\end{equation} 
Remarking that the first term corresponds to a term $n=0$ in the summation, the result can be written as
\begin{equation}
J_\nu(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\left[\frac{2^{-2n-\nu+2}}{\Gamma(n+\nu)}- 2^{-n+1}J_{n+\nu-1}(1)\right]\frac{ x^{\nu} B_n(x^2)}{n!} 
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks @ Paul Enta

Comment: Happy if it is useful...